# Problems with https protocol and Basic Authentication in java

Tags: java, https

i have to retrive a csv using https protocol and Basic Authentication in java. i used this code but the output stream retrived is an array with 250 zero. there are some error in my code?

```
    String webPage = url_a;
    String name = email;
String password = pass;


String authString = name + ":" + password;
byte[] authEncBytes = Base64.encodeBase64(authString.getBytes());
String authStringEnc = new String(authEncBytes);
URL url = new URL(webPage);
HttpsURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
urlConnection.addRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + authStringEnc);


urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
urlConnection.setAllowUserInteraction(false);
urlConnection.setDoInput(false);
urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
urlConnection.connect();

final OutputStream outs = urlConnection.getOutputStream();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to read the response, try urlConnection.getInputStrem() ... 
The names input/output are viewed from your point of view (as client). So output is what you send out to server, and input is what you receive from server.

Comment: thank you, that was a very stupid error that was killing me XDXD